# Como acessar atributo de relacionamento no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Na imagem abaixo vemos um típico exemplo de Collection no Laravel.
Podemos que ver em **relations** há um um outro Collection.

Como eu acesso isso na View?

Eu estou fazendo assim no Controller:

```
$users = User::with(['logs' => function($q) use ($startAt, $endAt){
    $q->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $startAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $q->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $endAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}]);
```

Sei que na View eu posso fazer um:

```
@foreach($users as $user)

@endforeach
```

A dúvida é como posso pegar o Collection 'Logs' ali dentro do Foreach para aquele usuário que está passando ali.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### GroupBy e Filter

```
$videoList = $user['logs']->filter(function($q){ 
    return $q->content->type == 'video'; 
})->groupBy('content_id');
```

Comment: Você não pode puxar a  $users['relations']['logs'] e loopar partindo dai ?

Comment: Posso. Mas é que estou usando o mesmo objeto para várias coisas. Mas vou testar as sugestões. Estou há um tempo sem mexer com Lavarel...

Comment: loopa como você fez, pega pelo array_key_exist (ou algum semelhante no laravel), e se bater a key com relations loopa denovo dentro do loop ja aberto pra pegar os logs#itens, ai não precisa abrir separado, mas acaba fazendo uma verificação a mais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com issso você deve conseguir retornar todos os logs contidos em $user.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->relations as $logs)
     $logs['logs']
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Antes de fazer isso eu preciso fazer um Filter e um GroupBy no Collection Logs. Mas o GroupBy não está funcionando.

Comment: Então, @Miguel, isso funciona. Porém, não leva em conta meu filtro no Controller. Isso que está me quebrando...

Comment: Logs está dentro de relations, de acordo com a imagem que ele postou, por isso percorri o array com o user , para depois percorrer $user->relations e retornar os dados de logs.

Comment: Daí tem que fazer outro for dentro do for do relations?

Comment: @DiegoSouza , como você esta tentando fazer o groupBy ?

Comment: Postei na pergunta.

Comment: Você pode tentar algo assim: $videoList = $user['logs']->filter(function($q){ 
    return $q->content->type == 'video'; 
})->groupBy('content_id')->pluck('content_id');

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do seu loop você pode obter a collection do relacionamento e então utilizar os métodos do laravel para tratar sua collection.

No link a seguir você pode consultar os metodo:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections

No caso seu código ficaria parecido com o seguinte:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   <?php
      $user->logs()->groupBy('coluna_que_você_deseja_agrupar');
   ?>
@endforeach
```

Consulte a documentação para saber como o groupBy funciona.

Ou se desejar somente utilizar a collection de logs, seu código ficaria assim:

```
@foreach($users as $user)

   @foreach ($user->logs() as $log )

   @endforeach

@endforeach
```